# Find all the intervals in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, intervals

I have xy numpy array with shape(2,600)

```py
array([[0.        , 0.01      ],
       [0.02      , 0.03      ],
       [0.04      , 0.05      ],
       ...,
       [1.21943121, 1.14205236],
       [1.07493206, 1.01916783],
       [0.97570154, 0.94530397]])
```

I need to find all the intervals in which the values of the second demention is less than zero. Mark them as + and print them with index from first dimention.

Output example:

```
 [0.00 0.04] +
 [0.04 0.08] -
 [0.08 0.10] +
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me!

Comment: please provide your attempt at a solution.

Comment: How is this correct? `[0.04 0.08] -`

Comment: This is just example output, minus values are farther

Answer (score 0):

This would filter out the intervals that have second value less than 0.

`filter = [i for i in arr if i[1] < 0]`

If you need the indices then,

```
ind = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
 if arr[i][1] < 0:
  ind.append(i)
```

In Numpy, it would be simply:

`np.where(arr[:,1] < 0)`

This will get you the indices.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I know how to filter values that <0 in second demention, but i don't understand how print intervals sequentially with index from first dimention